# call specific cell in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

In Microsoft Access, I am trying to fill a box in a form automatically.

I want the user to insert the discount_code in the form and the discount_amount will be called from the other table automatically.

for example, the user will insert "AA22" in the discount_code box.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNZVs.png)

then, we will find the row in the discount table that has "AA22" and select the discount amount(for example 20$) from the discount_amount column.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tca2x.png)

finally, in the form, the box of discount_amount should be automatically filled by 20$.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dntHf.png)

how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DLOOKUP()` function like

```
=DLOOKUP("[discount_amount]","[discount]","[discount_code]='" & [discount_id] & "'")
```

More about `DLOOKUP()` here from [Microsoft.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dlookup-function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937)

Comment: You can use same function to both `control source` of textbox as well as to `VBA`.